# iOS release updates

Tags: ios, updates, release

Is there any way the iOS developers be pre notified about the scheduled release date of Over-The-Air updates for new OS versions?
I have enrolled in apple developer program and I am getting updates in my mail on any beta releases and GM releases once available, but is there any way I could know when the actual version will be available for iPhone users over the air?
Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**
Apple does not provide precise dates for any of their OTA releases (except major ones, sometimes).

Comment: Ok, so when will Apple officially announce the release date of major version? It does'nt seem like developers are getting notified about the release date of major version via mail. How would we get to about it ?

Comment: They announce them 2 hours before they do, during the new iPhone's launch keynote ;) This is the best you will get. You won't have an official statement from Apple in your mail saying that iOS 9 will be released October 32nd at 23:42UTC.

Comment: Hmm, doubt raised when I read this blog 'http://9to5mac.com/2014/09/09/apple-releases-ios-8-gm-ahead-of-sep-17-public-release/', which was written on sept-09-2014 and it clearly states that 'iOS 8 is scheduled to be released over-the-air next week on September 17th for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch running iOS 7 .....'. So just wanted to know whether we could know this by some means, subscribing to apple RSS feeds or something else?

Comment: You can keep an eye on specialized blogs news. But most of the time, it will be educated guesses or unofficial information.

Comment: Okay.. great thanks!!!